# $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable with Cantors Diagonal argument (how to improve binary expansion specificity?)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I know it's spelled out more than usual, but this is an introduction to higher math class. If there's any way I can improve this, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Let $I=\left[0,1\right]=\{x\in \mathbb{R} \mid 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$. Let $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\{0,1\}$ be any function. We will show that there exists an $x \in I$ such that $x \notin f(n)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ demonstrating no surjection on $f : I \to \mathbb{N}$

In other words there is no number $x$ in the sequence $f_0, f_1, f_2, . . ..$

The number $f_m$ can be defined as $$f_m = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{a_{m,n}}{2^{n+1}}$$

If $f_m$ can be defined by more than one binary representation, we always use the representation terminating in $0$s to retain unique representations of all real numbers.

Thus, 
$f_0 = \frac{a_{0,0}}{2},  \frac{a_{0,1}}{2^2},  \frac{a_{0,2}}{2^3}$, . . .

$f_1 = \frac{a_{1,0}}{2},  \frac{a_{1,1}}{2^2},  \frac{a_{1,2}}{2^3}, $. . .

$f_ 2 =$ . . .

We can take the diagonals $(a_{0,0}, a_{1,1}, a_{2,2}, . . .)$ and invert them such that all $0$s are $1$s, and all $1$s are $0$s, creating a new sequence $(b_0, b_1, b_2, . . .)$

We define $x \in I$ as $$x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{b_n}{2^{n+1}}$$

The $n^{th}$ term in $f_n=a_n$ yet the $n^{th}$ term in $x = b_n$, and $a_n\neq b_n$ Thus, $f(n)\neq x$. Since there is no bijection between the infinite set $\left[0,1\right]$ and $\mathbb{N}$, $\left|[0,1]\right| > \left | \mathbb{N} \right |$.

Since $[0,1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ , then $\left|[0,1]\right| \leq \left| \mathbb{R} \right| $. Thus,

$$\mathbb{N} < \left|[0,1]\right| \leq \left | \mathbb{R} \right | $$ 
Proving $\left | \mathbb{R} \right |$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

This proof is not completely correct, due to the non-uniqueness of binary representations of real numbers.  For example, take any sequence ${f_m}$ such that $f_0 = 0.1_2$ and the $(k+1)$th binary digit of $f_k$ is $0$ for all $k>0$.  Then $x = 0.0\bar 1_2 = 0.1_2 = f_0$.

Comment: I appreciate that. I've added this sentence, "If $f_m$ can be defined by more than one binary representation, we always use the representation terminating in $0$s to retain unique representations of all real numbers." Is it specific enough?

Comment: @Forever_A_Student Nope, the same counterexample still holds.  In base $b>2$ you can avoid this by choosing digits such that $x$ never ends with an infinite string of $(b-1)$s.

Comment: What are b-1s? Also I understand the example  in base 10, but as I often get points off for minor word changes in my proofs. I'm trying to stick to the example that my Professor gave as much as possible. So that I will not increase the chances of loosing points on an upcoming final. Will you give me the right phrase that would make this work in base 2? Or, is it impossible to "choose" one type of representation for dyadics in this proof?

Comment: @Forever_A_Student If you are just concerned with your grade, don't worry.  The grader will never notice this counterexample if you don't mention it.

Comment: @Forever_A_Student By $(b-1)$s I mean the maximum digit for base $b$.  For instance, in base $2$ an infinite string of $1$s, in base $10$ an infinite string of $9$s, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your second displayed equation should have $x$ on the left-hand side, not $f_m$, and you should use "\mid" to typeset the vertical bar in the definition of $I$ (for  better spacing).

You might want to add a diagram as a visual aid to understand  the terminology "diagonal method".

You should probably add a sentence outlining the overall structure of the proof - something like "We show that if $f$ is an arbitrary function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $I$ then there is some element of $I$ not in the range of $f$ and so $f$ is not a surjection",

Comment: I've incorporated your suggestions. If they aren't specific enough, how should I have worded them? Thank you